# Handling URL rewriting for a multi-language website

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a multi-language website and I'm having a little trouble with rewriting URLs.

So lets say I want to rewrite URLs for the products page. I must have something like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/products/some-product-name-34.html (for english)

http://www.mywebsite.com/produits/some-product-name-34.html (for french)

There will also be some static pages like a privacy policy page. I must have something like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy.html (for english)

http://www.mywebsite.com/politique-de-confidentialite.html (for french)

Any ideea how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Do these pages have different content (one in english, one in frensh)? If so, why not provide these contents as seperate html-files?

Comment: @JochenJung: these pages have the same content.

Comment: @Gumbo, the question is how can I write the rules to work fine no matter of the language the user has selected.

Comment: Do you have access to the `<VirtualHost>` configuration? Also, where are these URLs being rewritten to? I assume there must be a common file that somehow should know what language to show, otherwise you could just have multiple files and wouldn't need any rewriting. It's hard to give suggestions without knowing what that page would be, though.

Answer (score 0):

This one would make the products accessible under its two names:

```
RewriteCond /products/some-product-name-34.html
RewriteRule /products/some-product-name-34.html /produits/some-product-name-34.html
```

That you have to do for all other files as well. Or if its just the directory, you like to rename

```
RewriteCond /products/(.*)$
RewriteRule /products/(.*)$ /produits/$1
```

would do.

Comment: I don't think this is ok because I can't enter the word (products, produits) in there. I need a placeholder for that word.